# How do I make non-square aspect ratio buttons in gridview?

Tags: android, android-gridview

I am trying to figure out how to make a rectangular buttoned grid using image adapter. Is there a way to change the height, so that its smaller than the width (to make horizontal rectangles)? I tried changing the padding, and editing the xml file to no luck. Thanks!

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return MainActivity.SIZE;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //ImageView imageView;
        TextView textView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            /*imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(16, 16, 16, 16);*/

            textView = new TextView(mContext);
            textView.setPadding(16,16,16,16);
            textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            textView.setText("Button");
            textView.setTextSize(25);
            textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        } else {
            //imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            textView = (TextView) convertView;
        }

        //imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image);

        //return imageView;
        return textView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

With some searching in the android documentations, found the layoutParams method!

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300, 175);
textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```